# Waveform in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, waveform

I'm trying to use `wavesurfer.js`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="waveform" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></div>
        <script src="wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                wavesurfer.init({
                    container: document.querySelector('#waveform'),
                    waveColor: 'violet',
                    progressColor: 'purple',
                    normalize: true
                });
                wavesurfer.load('sound.mp3');
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of the waveform, all I can see is a vertical line:

[image]

The sound file `sound.mp3` contains 12 seconds of human speech.

Comment: Is there an error? It doesn't look like `#waveform` is appended to the DOM

Comment: No error except `Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.` for `file:///build/wavesurfer-js-map.json`.

Comment: Are you opening it from HDD? Because `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///sound.mp3. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. ` You should run it from server

Comment: @Cheery Thank you for the reply. Yep, it's a local file. Where did you get that error message?